# Undefined when doing document.write() with button OnClick="counter"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming and would need some help, why the document.write() didn't work and basically the page crashes... Can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showText() {
var x;
var counter;
if ( x === 0) {
counter = 0;
x = 1;
}
counter = counter + 1;
document.write("Times clicked: " + counter);
}


</script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
showText();
</script>

<button onclick="showText();">Click Me!<button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `document.write()` after the page has been finished will implicitly destroy the page. That's just what it does. You'll have to decide upon another way to show the counter.

Comment: also you need to declare your variable outside of showText.

Answer (score 2):

#### Avoid using `document.write`

Quoting from the MDN Developer Network [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> Note: as `document.write` writes to the document stream, calling `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open` which will clear the document.

So basically, your issue is using `document.write` after the page has loaded: this will result in deleting the entire content of the page and displaying that string.

Also, your code doesn't work because your `count` variable is declared inside the `showText` function, and you're trying to access it outside of it, running into an error.

#### Solution

To make your code work you should create another element, let's say a `<p>` element, and display the text inside of it. Here's an example of a correct page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Click me!</button>
    <p id="txt">Times clicked: 0</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showText() {
            count++;
            text.textContent = "Times clicked: " + count;
        }

        var count = 0,
            button = document.getElementById("btn"),
            text = document.getElementById("txt");

        button.addEventListener("click", showText);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check out a **[live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/0gmj1eg2/)**.

Comment: `document.write()` is *not* deprecated. There's nothing wrong with using it when you know what it does and use it appropriately.

Comment: @Juhana my mistake, I thought it was deprecated too. Still not a good practice IMHO (especially for a newbie).

Comment: When I tried the solution by Marco Bonelli, and tried using the code to create the page, somewhy it showed a blank white screen.

Comment: @NewProgram I added a live demo link. I don't know what you're doing wrong, but my solution works, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/0gmj1eg2/

Comment: I exactly copy-pasted the text into a notepad, and renamed the extension to html, launched it in browser, and it didn't work.

Comment: @NewProgram again, you're doing something wrong, I don't know what without seeing any code, but it's not my fault